# What does "We'll be up to our butts in corpses" mean?

Tags: phrases

I was reading *The Watchmen* (a graphic novel) and stumbled across this expression in a conversation between two cops talking about Rorschach. I suppose it means "We'll have to put up a fight", but I am not sure.

Comment: I guess it's [this Rorschach](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_(comics)) rather than the inkblot Rorschach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A more common idiom is being *knee deep* or *up to your knees* in something, meaning that *something* reaches one's knees. When you are *up to your knees* in water, you have gone in to a point that you are definitely wet, and more importantly, there is so much water around, that walking gets more difficult (you move from walking to wading).

It is applied to other things as well, meaning that you are surrounded by a large amount of it, literally or figuratively (knee deep in sh!t means you are in a bunch of trouble).

In the same way, the person who said *We'll be up to our butts in corpses* means that once they are done with what they are going to do, corpses will be piled up around them up to the level of their behinds. Whether that will be literally the case is not relevant: the message is that there will be a fair amount of dead people, once they are done.

Note that the sentence as you quoted it is ungrammatical. It may be a typo on your side or an oversight of the editor, but it should either be ***we**'ll be up to **our** butts in corpses*, or ***I**'ll be up to **my** but in corpses*. It escapes me why one person would refer to multiple butts in this way.

Comment: agreed that it's ungrammatical, including in the "as English is actually spoken" sense.

Comment: A bit illogical sure, but ungrammatical I think no. Perhaps the 2nd party is positioned in such a way that his butt will be at the level of the corpses, but the rest of his body is not in the corpses. Maybe he's flying and his butt is hanging down, while only Rorschach is standing and must be *in* the corpses. Or, given that this is a metaphor, we are not necessarily constrained to physical situations. In any case, there are two things, "I", and "our butts", and I think there's no *grammatical* rule requiring them to be in any kind of agreement.

Comment: @Phil The title has been fixed by the asker now, so it was presumably just a typo. Even so, I cannot see any way for “I’ll be up to our butts in _X_” to be grammatical, barring parallel universes where multiple people’s back sides regularly attach themselves to single individuals. It’s as ungrammatical to me as asking, “Is it all right if I just help ourselves?” (in the _help yourself_ sense of taking something without waiting for someone to serve it to you).